# Setting ROOT directory in PHP

Tags: php, server

Within my PHP I wish to instead of using *../* I want to be able to just use ROOT/Directory/File

My host's actual root is filled with a variety of files therefore it is difficult to do it through the actual way.

I want a file path to be for example:

```
ACTUALROOT/WEBSITEROOT/DIR/DIR/FILE
```

The documentation on using *DIR* is incredibly confusing can anyone clear this up in a logical way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From **php** manual:

> __DIR__  The directory of the file. If used inside an include, the directory of the included file is returned. This is equivalent to
>   dirname (__FILE__). This directory name does not have a trailing slash
>   unless it is the root directory.

Comment: Which means if you have a file say "siteroot.php" with this in, it will be in the directory of this?

Comment: Which clears up what the DIR does however, as my question states how do you use this to find a directory. Say this was within a directory called `server` within the root file how do you 'go back' as to say.

Comment: May be you can use https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_constants.asp where you can define your directory and use the constant along with the required directory etc..